# HTML and GUIDs in IE8,9,10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, guid

I have a UL list where each LI child tag has an attribute named "value" and it's value is a GUID.
I have found that for one particular GUID, IE renders only the first part of the GUID (eg : if the guid is 93365457-30bc-45e4-a85a-b74728ec83fc then the value of the "value" attribute is just 93365457. For other GUIDs the value is rendered correctly.

You can test by opening this simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Guid on IE test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
         <li value="79c8c2b5-ea63-4a4e-8b2e-c55c8f814e83">1</li>
         <li value="93365457-30bc-45e4-a85a-b74728ec83fc">2</li>
         <li value="352c32a6-596e-4897-b297-7b5fb4a06bb1">3</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

The first and third li get rendered correctly, but the second does not. 
I've checked this by using IE's developer tools and by using javascript to read the value.

I've tested and duplicated this issue on IE 8,9 on Win2008 and IE 10 on Win 8

Is there any known fix for this issue?

I came across this issue while working with MS Project Server 2010 & Sharepoint 2010 (a PJS 2010 lookup type custom field gets rendered as an iframe that contains an ul like the one listed above in which the LI tags are the lookup items and the "value" attribute has the unique id of each lookup item).

**Later Edit :**

apparently all GUIDs / UUIDs where the first part is numeric end up truncated. The ones where the first part is alphanumeric do not

Comment: "Is there any known fix for this issue?" Stop writing invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm not writing it... read last paragraph...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the html5 draft, you can indeed have a value attribute for an li, but only those inside an **ordered** list (`<ol>`):

> If the element is a child of an ol element: value

*Source: [li spec on w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-li-element)*

Furthermore:

> The value attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the
>   ordinal value of the list item.

*Source: [value attribute for li on w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-li-value)*

Then, that's probably why IE is not retrieving the value properly: it doesn't need to in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires that the `value` attribute for a `li` element is a number. You will see that any GUID that has its first section made of only digits will behave in the same way. I think what IE does is it tries to parse it as a number, if it doesn't succeed then it either leaves it as is or if the first section is a number then it keeps only that.

If as you say that source is generated by the MS software then I guess there's nothing much you can do (except using another browser). Otherwise you could have simply used a custom attribute instead of `value`.

Comment: Other browser or attribute are not options that i have. IE is here to stay and i don't have control over the html rendering. But i understand the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: But how do you have to interact with that DOM? Can you alter it somehow (using javascript at least)?

Comment: I don't have control over the actual html rendering of components (in my scenario) but i can include my own JS files that implement the functionality i am after. I came across this issue by trying to show / hide the lookup items (aka the LIs) based on some condition. And i was using the value (aka the lookup item unique id) to do so.